# Keras model from NN schematic

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am a python Intermediate and Keras/NN beginner. I have implemented Keras models before from tutorials and want to try implementing one from a research paper. What does this schematic mean in relation to a Keras model?

[image]

Where "Input Cross-presence Matrix" is a incremental count of the number of times every pair of numbers (1-45) appeared together eg (1-2, 1-3 .. 1-45).

"Other input" is the incremental count of the number of times a number (1-45) appeared.

The output is a non-linear sigmoid of the presence or not a number (1-45) in an 8 wide array.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a [multi-input model](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models). The first input will go through a first Convolutional layer with kernel size 3. The output of this layer will go through 2 more of these layers, and then be added back to the original output of the first layer (basically a [residual/skip connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384602/implementing-skip-connections-in-keras) implementation). Then this output will be [concatenated](https://keras.io/layers/merge/) with an auxiliary input and fed to a fully-connected Dense layer, and then again to the last one.

Hope this helps as a start!